# Using TFS for automated testing

Tags: visual-studio, testing, tfs

First of all, I apologize if this is a dumb question and has a million answers.  I've not found anything that explains quite what I'm looking for in depth.

So then:  My company utilizes TFS for our testing management.  Sort of.  We use GitHub independently from it for source management, we use Jira independently frm it for QA management, as well as bug reporting and tracking.
We "use" TFS for tracking the pass or fail for test cases.  But they are in no way connected to any of our automation, we still require user presence to check automated tests and pass the test case on TFS.   At that point, we should just be using a spreadsheet.

What I so dearly need help with is some sort of learning resource that focuses entirely on the test management and test automation aspects of TFS.  I've been searching around but everything I find tends to focus on TFS as a bug reporting and source management system, rather than an automated test system.
And it's 100% possible (in fact, 100% likely) that we're simply utilizing the system wrong.  The person who set up TFS originally left abruptly and we've been flailing with it ever since.

In particular we've had problems with:

Hooking a test case into an automated test (Our test code is one large data-driven CodedUI project with specific test methods to test specific things.  Ideally we would be able to apply a test method result to a correlated test case)

Mass assignment of test cases.  I spent a good hour today just assigning smoke tests to people because there was no way I could figure out to query "Test IDs 1300 through 1600 with configuration Windows 7 64 bit" and then mass assign within a sprint.

Proper organization of test cases and suites.  My predecessor arranged everything in a particular sprint in a classic Tree-Form style, using static test suites.  E.G. The sprint itself would be a static suite with a series of children static suites, which they themselves had static suites in.  This looks nice format-wise, but is an absolute nightmare to manage (See the above issue, it's why it took an hour)

Basically I need some sort of resource I can learn from to tell me how to properly utilize TFS for these things.

Comment: TFS really isn't intended to be a testing tool in isolation from the other features. The testing stuff works best if you're using TFS for project management (test cases tied to user stories/PBIs), source control and build (test suites tied to builds and executed on test agents)

Comment: Which in no way surprises me.  It all seems very heavily integrated into visual studio and source management, but the powers that be are very stubborn about us using this for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look to Pluralsight's Microsoft Test Manager course.

http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/microsoft-test-manager-2013#!

And the automations course:

http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/codedui-test-automation

These will both give you a detailed look at the capabilities.